# Is it possible to format the root boot disk with Ubuntu still running?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to boot Ubuntu, and format the root / boot disk whilst Ubuntu is still running.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "boot disk"? Do you want to reformat the root partition?

Comment: Yes, reformat the root partition.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be possible to write directly to a device while it is mounted, so if `/dev/sda1` is your root partition, writing to `/dev/sda1` with something like `mkfs` or `dd` *should* just result in an error message.

It may be possible though to write to `/dev/sda` (that is, the whole disk), so it could still be possible to shoot yourself in the foot like that.

You can also use `rm` on `/` with the arguments `-rf` and `--no-preserve-root`[1] which should delete all files in the filesystem, but of course that's not actually formatting.

If you manage to do one of these things, don't expect Ubuntu to continue working though.

[1] I intentionally didn't post the full command so that no one accidentally copy-pastes that into a shell and loses all his data.

Answer (score 0):

If "root boot disk" means first boot device, then *yes* it's possible and feasible, but it's also complicated and should be done carefully.  To learn more study the workings of some tiny [Linux distros that load everything in RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions_that_run_from_RAM).